# @spring.url macro is not getting HTML escaped

Tags: spring, freemarker, html-escape-characters

I am using spring-boot + freemarker (standard initialiser project ).

I have a line in my .ftlh file

```
<a href="<@spring.url '/${customer.email}' />"
           class="zenith-link"
           id="use-qr-link">${customer.email}
        </a>
```

but when I inject `"><script>alert("Boo!")</script>` as the customer email it is not escaped (and hence my app has XSS vulnerability)

Is there any way I can set the HtmlEscape as true

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the source code (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/spring.ftl), and not only there's no option to enable escaping, but they have deliberately disabled escaping there (with `?no_esc`):

```
<#macro url relativeUrl extra...>
  <#if extra?? && extra?size!=0>
     ${springMacroRequestContext.getContextUrl(relativeUrl,extra)?no_esc}
  <#else>
     ${springMacroRequestContext.getContextUrl(relativeUrl)?no_esc}
  </#if>
</#macro>
```

I don't know why. Besides, this thing (along with lot of other macros there) should be a `#function`, not a `#macro`. Then the user has full control over escaping, or however they want to use the result. (Anyway, looking at the source code it's clear that whoever did it didn't invest into getting know the template language.)